# Is it possible to roll using the controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, star-wars-battlefront-2015

Is it possible to roll in Star Wars Battlefront (the 2015 version) by using the controller on Xbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/720951-star-wars-battlefront/73475434), while strafing, hold the crouch button to roll. They worded it as:

> Hold the crouch button while strafing right or left and you'll be rolling in no time. Leia and Han had been able to do it already prior to this update.

**However**, another person said it's double tap the crouch button while strafing.  I also saw this answer on [another post](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/forums/discussion/36006/combat-roll).

Comment: @hyperviper11 which one was it? I'd like to edit my answer to whichever it is.

Comment: it was the double-tap